# AWX on Kubernetes trying to add host folder to project directory on container for AWX UI to have access to local playbooks

Tags: kubernetes, containers, ansible-awx

Working with AWX on Kubernetes I was able to create a local folder and pass it to the web container but the AWX UI does not see the playbooks but the container does.

Can anyone share documentation on how to expose from a localhost /path to the AWX UI?

Here is my deployment file:

> ---

```
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: awx
spec:
  service_type: nodeport
  projects_persistence: true
  projects_storage_access_mode: ReadWriteOnce
  web_extra_volume_mounts: |
    - name: static-data
      mountPath: /var/lib/projects
    - name: manual-projects
      mountPath: /var/lib/awx/projects


  extra_volumes: |
    - name: static-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: public-static-data-pvc
    - name: manual-projects
      hostPath:
        path: /var/lib/awx/projects
```

When I execute this on the container I'm able to see the path and file

```
> [lab01@localhost awx-operator]$ kubectl exec -it deploy/awx-web -c
> awx-web -n awx -- ls -l /var/lib/awx/projects/
> -rwxrwxr-x. 1 awx root 142 Jan 31 21:34 playbook.yml
```

but on the AWX UI I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `kubectl port-forward`

Example

```
kubectl port-forward pods/awx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx 8080:80
```

Where 8080 is your local port, you can try to browse locally with `localhost:8080` for your UI

Comment: Thanks but what I'm trying to do is expose a local file path on the host server to the container.  The container can see the file but the AWX UI does not.